# Assert on most recent call arguments for Sinon spy

Tags: sinon

In my implementation code, I have an update function that may be called multiple times. The updates are complete, which is to say that if you call `updateFn(A)` then `updateFn(B)`, "A" will not matter and only "B" will be in effect. I could write an assertion like so:

```
assert(updateFn.calledWith(B));
```

Which on the surface appears to be a good test. However, that assertion would still pass if the actual calls were `updateFn(A)` → `updateFn(B)` → `updateFn(A)`, which would be incorrect behavior for the system in question.

What I would like to write is an assertion on only the most recent called arguments. Is there a good way to do this with Sinon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Chai assertions you can do:

```
expect(updateFn.lastCall.args).to.eql([B]);
```

Where `[B]` is the array of expected arguments.

Comment: you may want to use .deep.eq to compare arrays